# Laravel OAuth Authorization Header for FitBit API

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I have been struggling for days now to find a decent solution for Laravel but to no avail.

There are many libraries out there that at one point may have worked to provide a Laravel - FitBit API OAuth integration however after trying over 15 different ones and none of them working I am stuck.

Reading the [FitBit Documentation](https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/#access-token-request) I see that once you receive a token you must swap the authorization code with an access token. To do this you need to send an authorization header like this:

```
POST https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50X2lkOmNsaWVudCBzZWNyZXQ=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=22942C&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback&code=1234567890
```

I have tried using guzzle and a few other libraries for sending the requests but none of them support the format that FitBit require.

I've seen sites with FitBit API integrated so there must be a solution for this.

If anyone has managed to integrate the FitBit API please let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that most REST clients build headers with associative arrays. You will likely need to construct your own curl request to get your `access token` so you can use that specific header format, however, taking a quick look at the API, it looks like you should be able to use a library like guzzle for all other calls.

Comment: I haven't used CURL in a long time and it was very simple usage, could you possibly point me in the right direction with how I might go about getting the access token using CURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a fitbit account, so I can't test this and it will probably need some tweaking, but I would start with something like:

```
class FitbitConnection{

    public function getToken($request_url, $client_id, $client_secret, $code, $redirect_uri){

        // base64 encode the client_id and client_secret
        $auth = base64_encode("{$client_id}:{$client_secret}");
        // urlencode the redirect_url
        $redirect_uri = urlencode($redirect_uri);
        $request_url .= "?client_id={$client_id}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={$redirect_uri}&code={$code}";

        // Set the headers
        $headers = [
                        "Authorization: Basic {$auth}",
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    ];

            // Initiate curl session
            $ch = curl_init();
            // Set headers
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            // Options (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            // Execute the curl request and get the response
            $response = curl_exec($ch);

            // Throw an exception if there was an error with curl
            if($response === false){
                throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
            }

            // Get the body of the response
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $responseBody = substr($response, $header_size);
            // Close curl session
            curl_close($ch);

            // Return response body
            return $responseBody;

    }
}
```

You should note that I've commented out

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`

You can put this option back in if you get an SSL certificate problem on your localhost, but you shouldn't use it in production .

You can then just do something like:

```
try{
    $fitbitConnection = new FitbitConnection();
    $token_response = $fitbitConnection->getToken("https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token","22942C","client_secret","1234567890","http://www.example.com");
    echo $token_response;
}catch(Exception $e){
    // curl error
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's almost working however I'm getting this error response. http://imgur.com/tUoM4ov which is odd as I can see the grant type is included in the request. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it seems Fitbit have some slightly confusing documentation. They don't want you to send the request parameters in the header, they want you to append those parameters to the request url. I will update my answer to reflect that, but you should now be able to use a package like guzzle for this if you don't want to use this custom curl method.

Comment: I noticed that on another re-read of the docs I saw that the parameters all wanted to be in the CURL body so I altered your code and now the Authorization code is invalid so I think that's progress. Will try your altered solution now.

Comment: Still getting `message: "Authorization code invalid: 99179855123fab25cfe58e28c360a21a87f4c6dc"` error.

Comment: For the authorisation code the docs state `The code is only valid for 10 minutes`, so if you authorised you app more than 10 minutes ago you will need to get a new authorisation code by going through the authorisation process again.

Comment: I'm revoking app permissions every time to force it to go through the first step again. Still telling me it's invalid.

Comment: Are you updating your call to `getToken()` with the new code returned from the authorisation process?

Comment: It's working perfectly. I was using the wrong method prior to this which was generating the wrong `code`. Access token now working and on to the API calls. Thanks so much for your help.